# Add single dependency package to maven artifact

Tags: java, maven, package

Given an example dependency defined as:

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Is it possible to **add** a single package from that dependency (e.g. org.apache.commons.lang.math) to a final jar package?

Comment: What your use case here? What do you want to achieve? Because the simple answer is: you can't (easily) do that.

Comment: The output jar file will be used standalone so it needs to contain some dependency classes. And I don't want to include all project dependencies because some of them are irrelevant and simply take disk space.

Comment: So you're making a final assembly that contains some dependencies of your project, and for `commons-lang` you want to strip out some packages in it? If you're worried about disk space, just include the relevant dependencies with the [Assembly Plugin](//maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) (include what you want in a [dependency set](//maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet)). You won't get much disk space benefit by remove packages, and it can lead to weird bugs (what if you're keeping a package but it turns out it depends on another one?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *shade maven plugin* to create fat jar with your application.

Shade plugin can automatically remove all classes of dependencies that are not used by the project.

Please look at example in shade projekt maybe useful for you:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html